# solr text indexed as array of text

Tags: solr

Im trying to index the following document in solr 6.0.0:

```
{
    "content_t":"A bunch of content"
}
```

And it's indexed as:

```
{
    "content_t":["A bunch of content"] 
}
```

what am I to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have added the attribute as `multivalued = true` for the field `content_t`.

A `multivalued` field is useful when there are more than one value present for the field. As you don't want to store the same in multivalue form, remove the attribute for the same field.

Remove the same and restart the server.

Re-index the data.

Comment: Is it possible it came out this way from the distribution zip? Because I just executed `bin/solr start -e cloud -nopromt` right out of the box

Comment: I actually used `dynamicFields` so I haven't touched any configurations except creating a collection. This guide - http://yonik.com/solr-tutorial/ - specifies that `_t` is for text and `_txt` is for multivalued text.

Comment: You can modify the managed schema file to `_txt` or `_t` to turn of the field being `multivalued`. Or you can redefine a schema.xml for you specific document.