# String type is giving array of string in Solr, Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr

I have a `Spring Boot` Application and I am trying to store data directly to Solr. Following is my `Solr Model class`

```
public class AnalyticsGeoLocationSolr {

    @Id
    @Indexed(name = "id", type = "int")
    private Integer id;

    @Indexed(name = "ipaddress", type = "string") // defined as String
    private String ipAddress;

    @Indexed(name = "country_name", type = "string") // defined as String
    private String countryName;

// Getters and Setters
```

Here you can see that `ipAddress` and `CountryName` both are defined as `String` as `type="string"`. However, the Solr is saving these variables as an `array of String`. Following is display of these fields in `Solr` (`as Json`):

```
"ipAddress":["59.103.217.207"],
"countryName":["Pakistan"],
// Other fields
```

[image]

Now, I want these String Objects to be stored as string i.e the expected Output should be "ipAddress":"59.103.217.207" not an array (with [ ] around).

Comment: The question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388829/spring-data-solr-is-creating-fieldtype-as-text-general-even-though-we-mention-as

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37042732/solr-text-indexed-as-array-of-text

Comment: @pringi thanks for replying. Yes this is the way to solve the problem but this approach is possible to manually change data type in solr schema. I am looking a way to do this in `spring boot`